# Foreign key twice in same table for different columns?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, constraint, referential-integrity

Server: MariaDB 10.3.21
Client: MariaDB 10.4.12

Given the following structure/data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `main`;
CREATE TABLE `main` (
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

LOCK TABLES `main` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `main` VALUES ('bar','this is another test');
INSERT INTO `main` VALUES ('foo','this is a test');
UNLOCK TABLES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `referenceData`;
CREATE TABLE `referenceData` (
  `primaryName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `secondaryName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`primaryName`),
  KEY `referenceData_FK_1` (`secondaryName`),
  CONSTRAINT `referenceData_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`primaryName`) REFERENCES `main` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `referenceData_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`secondaryName`) REFERENCES `main` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

LOCK TABLES `referenceData` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `referenceData` VALUES ('bar','bar');
INSERT INTO `referenceData` VALUES ('foo','bar');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

One can update/delete row 1 in table `main` just fine and the CASCADE performs as expected on table `referenceData`. However, when one attempts to update row 2 in table `main` (e.g. via `UPDATE main SET name = 'bar2' WHERE name = 'bar'`), the following error is returned:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`referenceData`, CONSTRAINT `referenceData_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`secondaryName`) REFERENCES `main` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

If one attempts a delete via `DELETE FROM main WHERE name = 'bar'`, however, it works fine.

What, quite frankly, in tarnation? Why does this error occur when both columns are the same value during an update, and why isn't a delete affected?

Comment: Your data model doesn't make much sense, unfortunately. Also, primary keys are not meant to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `main`;
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main` (
>   `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
>   `description` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
>
> LOCK TABLES `main` WRITE;
> INSERT INTO `main` VALUES ('bar','this is another test');
> INSERT INTO `main` VALUES ('foo','this is a test');
> UNLOCK TABLES;
>
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `referenceData`;
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `referenceData` (
>   `primaryName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
>   `secondaryName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`primaryName`, `secondaryName`),
>   CONSTRAINT `referenceData_FK_primary` FOREIGN KEY (`primaryName`) REFERENCES `main` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
>   CONSTRAINT `referenceData_FK_secondary` FOREIGN KEY (`secondaryName`) REFERENCES `main` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
>
> LOCK TABLES `referenceData` WRITE;
> INSERT INTO `referenceData` VALUES ('bar','bar');
> INSERT INTO `referenceData` VALUES ('foo','bar');
> UNLOCK TABLES;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM main;
> SELECT * FROM referenceData;
> ```
>
> ```
> name | description         
> :--- | :-------------------
> bar  | this is another test
> foo  | this is a test      
>
> primaryName | secondaryName
> :---------- | :------------
> bar         | bar          
> foo         | bar
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d1a697baa22bdd09088c8ed88a69e64c)*

Only `referenceData` DDL was edited - look.

---

> when one attempts to update row 2 in table main (e.g. via
>
> ```
> UPDATE main SET name = 'bar2' WHERE name = 'bar')
> ```
>
> , the following error is returned:
>
> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`referenceData`, CONSTRAINT `referenceData_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`secondaryName`) REFERENCES `main` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
>   If one attempts a delete via DELETE FROM main WHERE name = 'bar', however, it works fine.

The reason of this issue is a record where both `primaryName` and `secondaryName` have the same value. Cascade update is performed not "by record" but "by reference" - i.e. 2 separate cascade operations attempts will be executed. And when the first cascade operation is performed (by one field) the check for another field fails (`main` table has one value whereas edited record needs in 2 different values - both old and new - at the same time). And I do not see the way to solve this issue (except use insert into `main` - update `referenceData` - remove from `main`)...

Comment: nope, still has the same issue.
`UPDATE main SET name = 'bar2' WHERE name = 'bar'` gives `ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (testdb2.referenceData, CONSTRAINT referenceData_FK_secondary FOREIGN KEY (secondaryName) REFERENCES main (name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)`

Comment: @brentsaner Added.

Comment: i actually found a different way in-code to handle this.

so i removed the `NOT NULL` for the `secondary` column in the `referenceData` table, and in-code i'll just say "if secondary is null, assume secondary = primary".

it's just a shame i can't really represent that fully in-database.

thanks for the explanation, though! i thought cascades were done by record. good to know.

Comment: @brentsaner Yes, this trick will work - but this is a trick, not an issue solution...

Comment: yep. it works well enough, though, and with an added CHECK, i think i'll have the exact behaviour i need in a reliable manner, if not a little extra external logic.

Comment: @brentsaner You must add triggers BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE, check `NEW.secondaryName` and set it to NULL if it is equal to `NEW.primaryName`.

Comment: @brentsaner `CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi BEFORE INSERT ON referenceData FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.secondaryName=CASE WHEN NEW.secondaryName != NEW.primaryName THEN NEW.secondaryName END;`, and the same for BEFORE UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the constraints are enforcing that the value in the "parent" and "child" records *must* be the same *at all times*.

Trying to update the "parent" value will fail because there are "child" values that still have the *old* value.

Trying to update the "child" values will fail because they're different from the "parent" value.

The only [sane] way to to do this is:

- Insert a new "parent" record with the new value,
- Update all the "child" records to the new value, and then
- Delete the old, "parent" value.

Yes, that's a *lot* of work, which is why others have, quite rightly, said that Primary Key values should be chosen so that they *do not change*.

Here, you're probably working with *a few* records.  Imagine the impact on your database server if you wanted to make this sort of change on *millions* of records ...   Your DBMS might well take you off its Christmas Card List.

> LOCK TABLES referenceData WRITE;
>
> . . .
>
> UNLOCK TABLES;

MySQL is plenty clever enough to handle multi-user change concurrency without the potentially *huge* Application performance bottlenecks caused by locking *entire tables* when you *really* don't need to.